# How to restrict tablet screen orientation

Tags: android, android-orientation, device-orientation

I want to restrict my tablet to launch at specific screen orientation like landscape? I'm taking here about the whole tablet not a specific app, and for sure I'm not taking about locking off the **Auto Rotate** in the tablet after it launches, I'm taking about restricting the tablet to launch at landscape/protrait.

Comment: For that you should set `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` attribute to your `Application` or `Activity`

Comment: thanks, but I'm not taking about an app or activity, I'm asking about the whole tablet orientation

Comment: @MR I dont think there is way...

Comment: @MD may be you are right, I hope you not :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, **an app** that will run just one time.

create an app and add a permission to it's manifest to **write_settings** & **listen-to-boot** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

then make a `receiver` class which **extends** `BroadcastReceivertype`, with the fowlloing permissions:

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" 
        android:name="com.example.BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then in the `onReceive()` method of the `receiver` class:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        //To handle device rotation 
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.USER_ROTATION, Surface.ROTATION_90); // 0 for default, then 90, 180, 270
```

Then run this app just one time to write that permissions to the system, and then you don't need it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import android.provider.Settings;
    public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled)
    {
          Settings.System.putInt( context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
    }

//adding permission

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: it's not an app level question, it's a tablet level question

Comment: are you need to auto rotate screen in tablet ?

Answer (score 0):

Create file `orientationLock.xml` and put this in it - `res/values/orientationLock.xml` (Name doesn't matter) -

```
    <bool name="orien_lock">true</bool>
```

Now create a folder (If you don't already have it) named `values-sw600dp` and `values-xlarge` in res and put this in it -

```
    <bool name="orien_lock">false</bool>
```

Then, in the onCreate method of your Activities put this:

**To lock in portrait mode**

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.orien_lock)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

**To lock in landscape mode**

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.orien_lock)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

---

**Explanation**

On devices that are more than 600dp in width (mini tabs) or x-large (on pre-Android 3.2), the value of orien_lock will become false (as defined by us) as the file in `values-sw600dp` will be called and the it will be locked in landscape/portrait mode.

Comment: you mean the `res/values/` of what? `/system` ?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat, I recommend you to go through API guides before asking questions here - http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

for each activity in your tablet you can use this in your manifest file
i'm doing the similar task its working and its very easy.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.abc.MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: But this will disable rotation for all devices

Comment: what do you mean by each activity in my tablet

Comment: I mean for each layout which is visible to the user

Comment: you are building a app for tabs only or for both??
if the answer is for both
do you want to set the fixed orientation for tablet only not for mobile??

Comment: well, the layouts here is the layouts of an app? I'm taking about the whole tablet (lock screen, homepage, ...etc)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I reached to a solution a posted it as an answer :)